# Cant reference the subform to repopulate the recordsource Runtime Error 2450 Cant find the main form

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I have a MainForm *Groups_Members* with 2 SubForms as DataSheets *Groups* and *Members*. I am trying to populate the *Members* subform depending on the selected row in the *Groups* subform.

I am in the Subform *Groups* and this code works for the the Form *Members* repopulating the recordsource according to the selected row (more accurately by clicking on the id field, which is not really what i want but that is a more cosmetical issue) :

```
Private Sub ID_Click()
    Dim SQLsource As String
    
    SQLsource = "SELECT [tPerson].[ID], [tPerson].[Anrede], [tPerson].[TitelVorn], [tPerson].[Vorname], [tPerson].[Nachname], [tPerson_Funktion].[Funktion], [tPerson_tInstitution].[Wochenstunden], [tPerson_tInstitution].[tInstitution_ID] " & _
                "FROM (tPerson INNER JOIN tPerson_tInstitution ON [tPerson].[ID] =[tPerson_tInstitution].[tPerson_ID]) INNER JOIN tPerson_Funktion ON [tPerson].[ID] =[tPerson_Funktion].[tPerson_ID] " & _
                "Where [tPerson_tInstitution.tInstitution_ID] = " & CurrentRecord & " ;"
    
    If CurrentProject.AllForms("Members").IsLoaded = True Then
        Forms("Members").RecordSource = SQLsource        
    End If
End Sub
```

However adapting it to work for the Subform "Members" within the MainForm "Groups_Members" hasn't been successful and i haven't been able to figure out why.

This

```
Forms!["Praxen_und_Mitarbeiter"]!["Mitarbeiter"].Form.RecordSource = SQLsource
```

Gives me an runtime error 2450 cant find Form *Groups_Members* although the form is right in front of me.

and this

```
Me.Parent!("Mitarbeiter").Forms.RecordSource = SQLsource
```

prompts a Type Mismatch Error

I am clearly missing something and would appreciate anyone pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Is the subform container named Mitarbeiter? If code is behind Group subform: `Me.Parent.Mitarbeiter.Form.RecordSource`. Review https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround described in the link provided by June7 works: https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp

The Short Version: Create an invisible Control Element on the Main Form and set the Control Source Property to the value in Subform A. Then Link corresponding the Value in Subform B to this Control Element.

This provides the desired effect. The referencing oddities remain unresolved but thats for another time.

Thanks to everyone who invested their time and to June7 for providing a solution.